# Rails - Retrieve data from upper tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: Brand and Campaign where Brand has_many Campaigns. I'd like to get my current brand when I work with any brand.

The fallowing codes just writes "Brand" instead of all of Brands names.

My campaign model include:

```
 class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
```

My Bradn model:

```
 class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns
```

This is my campaigns_conroller:

```
def index
        @campaign=Campaign.all
        @brand=Brand.all
    end
```

and this is my index view

```
<% @campaign.each do |campaign| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= @brand.name %></td>
        <td><%= campaign.title %></td>
```

The 'campaign.title' works properly. I have retrieved just 'Brand' text instead of Brands name.

Can anybody say what I should do?

Comment: You should also read about n+1 problem (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). Fetching data in your controller in this way is very unefficient.

Answer (score 1):

First some changes to your `index` :

```
def index
  @campaigns = Campaign.includes(:brand).all # (1) Plural naming to reflect its a collection of objects, (2) One call to the DB to fetch both campaigns and associated brands, read about include
end
```

Then, (you already figured how to access associated objects), difference is with [:includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) this won't fire a nother DB call:

```
<% @campaigns.each do |campaign| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= campaign.brand.name %></td>
    <td><%= campaign.title %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@brand` is an array with all the brands, I'm not sure what element you try to show.

I guess you want the brand for every campaign.

```
<td><%= campaign.brand.name %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the brand *of the campain*. You can access a belongs_to model by the name of the association:

```
<% @campaign.each do |campaign| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= campaign.brand.name %></td>
    <td><%= campaign.title %></td>
```